# Why are my Cucumber definition steps undefined in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have an android application project that I want to add automated tests in it. For that I would like to use Cucumber for java in Android Studio and execute those tests directly into my IDE (with a Run/Debug configuration).

I am on Windows 7 sp1 64 bits using Android Studio 0.8.9. I've added the plugins `Gherkin` version 134.1007 and `Cucumber for Java` version 134.1007. I use the following libraries for Cucumber :

- cucumber-android-1.1.8
- cucumber-core-1.1.8
- cucumber-html-0.2.3
- cucumber-java-1.1.8
- cucumber-junit-1.1.8
- cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3
- gherkin-2.12.2
- robotium-solo-5.2.1

This is my Project structure :

```
TruckCalibrator/
    .idea/
    app/
        build/
        libs/
            [libraries listed above in .jar format]
        src/
            main/
                java/
                    com/
                        novomnetworks/
                            formeval/
                                truckcalibrator/
                                    MainActivity.java
                res/
                AndroidManifest.xml
            test/
                assets/
                    features/
                        app_start.feature
                java/
                    com/
                        novomnetworks/
                            formeval/
                                truckcalibrator/
                                    test/
                                        CucumberTest.java
            build.gradle
    build/
    gradle/
```

This is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
}
```

This is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.test" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        tools:replace="icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="form-eval.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.database" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Cucumber step definitions file (`CucumberTest.java`) :

```
package com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

import com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.MainActivity;
import com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.R;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

/**
 * Created by rroyer on 2014-10-24.
 */
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
/*@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true,
        tags = "@tags",
        features = "src/test/assets/features/",
        format = { "pretty","html: cucumber-html-reports", "json: cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" },
        dryRun = false,
        glue = "com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.test" )*/
public class CucumberTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private static final String TAG = "CucumberTest";

    Solo solo;

    public CucumberTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    protected void before() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp");
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        getActivity().resetDB();
    }

    @After
    protected void after() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "tearDown");
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Given("^I started the app$")
    public void i_started_the_app() throws Throwable {
        solo.waitForActivity(MainActivity.class);
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("I should see the action bar")
    public void I_should_see_the_action_bar() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(getActivity().getMenu());
    }

    @Given("I am on the clients list")
    public void I_am_on_the_clients_list() throws Exception {
        solo.waitForFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_clients);
    }

    @Then("^I should see the clients list header$")
    public void I_should_see_the_clients_list_header() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(solo.searchText(solo.getString(R.string.clients)));
        assertTrue(solo.searchText(solo.getString(R.string.sorted_by)));
        assertNotNull(solo.getView(R.id.clients_spinner));
    }

    @Then("I should see the new client button")
    public void I_should_see_the_new_client_button() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(solo.getView(R.id.action_new_client).isShown());
    }

    @Then("^I should see the clients list$")
    public void I_should_see_the_clients_list() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(solo.getView(R.id.clients));
    }
}
```

And this is my feature file :

```
Feature: Démarrage de l'app
  Scenario: La barre de menu devrait s'afficher
    Given I started the app
    Then I should see the action bar
  Scenario: La liste des clients devrait s'afficher
    Given I started the app
    Then I should see the clients list header
    And I should see the new client button
    And I should see the clients list
```

When I run my Cucumber test configuration, (screenshot bellow) [image: Run/Debug configuration screenshot of my Cucumber test file] The features are found but my step definitions are not. The output says

```
Undefined step: Given  I started the app
Undefined step: Then  I should see the action bar
Undefined step: Given  I started the app
Undefined step: Then  I should see the clients list header
Undefined step: And  I should see the new client button
Undefined step: And  I should see the clients list

2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
6 Steps (6 undefined)
0m0,000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I started the app$")
public void i_started_the_app() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

[other similar suggestions...]
```

I've searched the web for a whole day without finding the correct way to link my step definitions file. Every post I find seems to tell people to mention the test package in the configuration field `Glue` and this is what I've done, but it's no use. If you look closely to my CucumberTest.java file, you can see that I tried with a `@CucumberOptions` annotation too but it did not change the result. I also tried with and without the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first look, it seems your target package in the test app manifest is wrong - com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.test - remove .test

Comment: I already tried with and without, I also tried to put my CucumberTest class not in the test package (so it is the same package as my MainActivity class), but I got the same errors

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an exception: `throw new PendingException();`

in

```
@Given("^I started the app$")
    public void i_started_the_app() throws Throwable {
        solo.waitForActivity(MainActivity.class);
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Cucumber is not even able to find that `i_started_the_app` method, so what is the deal with its content? Plus it is exactly what the error message tells me to put in my method.

Comment: You have to remove throw new PendingException(); from your code. That line throws exactly the message that you see in your traces. What cucumber is saying you is that you can use that template, but you have to remove that line. Remove that line and use CucumberOptions rather than @RunWith

Comment: I removed the `throw new PendingException();` line and replaced the `@RunWith` annotation with the `@CucumberOptions` annotation, but I get the exact same error. The error does not mention anywhere to remove the throw exception, it tells to create methods with throw exception commands...

Comment: Another issue can be the constructor. I have `public CucumberTest (SomeDependency dependency) {
  super(MainActivity.class);
 }`

Comment: What is SomeDependency? What kind of dependency should my class have?

Comment: At the begining SomeDependency can be empty. That class is used to share dependencies between all the step classes that you define. So for example you can create the empty `public class SomeDependency extends AndroidTestCase {}`

Comment: I've added this constructor, but still got the same errors :(

Comment: Another problem that I had is the packet where I had the CucumberTest class. Try to move it to another package. If you remove that class, do you get the same error?

Comment: Like I said in a comment of my question, I tried to have my cucumber test class in a package named exactly like the one my tested class is in (`com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator`), and I also tried puting it in a package test (`com.novomnetworks.formeval.truckcalibrator.test`), but none of the two did the trick. And when I delete my test class, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and I think I solved it. First, we need to use `androidTestCompile` configurations on all cucumber related libraries. Note that we need to use @jar qualifier for cucumber-android library to avoid gradle getting the apklib file instead of the jar file. For example :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:gherkin:2.12.2'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.0@jar'
}
```

Secondly, we don't need to use cucumber-java plugin for Android Studio. We need to run the test on the emulator/device, and I can't find a way to set that up with cucumber-java plugin. Instead, just use Android Test for your run configurations and set the Specific Instrumentation Runner to `cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation`.

And the last thing I noticed is that you don't need to use `@RunWith` annotation. Just use `@CucumberOptions` on one of your classes, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should be in folder `src/androidTest` instead of `src/test`

Also I would separate the CucumberTest.java into one class for Cucumber Runner with the configuration annotations and a separate class extending from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` containing your glue code.

Here you have a running example for Android Studio using Cucumber and Espresso instead of Robotium:

https://github.com/neoranga55/CleanGUITestArchitecture

Comment: I can confirm that your test is running in android studio, if we run it using the CucumberTestRunner.java, is there any way that we could run it one scenario at a time for easier testing method?

Comment: I use tags and then when launching the test I filter by tag to run only one test case, like: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Ptags="@test-scenario-whatever-id-001"